# VBA - How to determine the outcome of an IF statement based on the sub that called the sub it is in?

Tags: vba

First time poster but long time reader. I finally have a question that is either not here or I simply can't phrase it correctly enough to return an answer.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a single sub that I can call from other subs, that is 90% the same for everything and only changes the last 10% based on the sub that called it (possibly via an IF statement)

maybe something like:

```
Sub A()
Call Main
End Sub

Sub B()
Call MAIN
End Sub

Sub MAIN()
If Sub A called Sub MAIN Then
Answer = 1
elseif: Sub B called Sub MAIN Then
Answer = 2
Endif
End sub
```

I'm thinking this may not be possible but would be great to use something like this rather than writing a heap of almost identical subs.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an optional parameter if it's called from a specific location:

```
Sub A()
    MAIN
End Sub

Sub B()
    MAIN True
End Sub

Sub MAIN(Optional fromB As Boolean = False)
    If fromB Then
        Answer = 2
    Else
        Answer = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried the above but I always get the same answer (1). The only difference is I don't have 'TRUE' next to MAIN in sub B as it's the expected end of statement, would that make a difference? I won't always know which sub is going to call MAIN as it will be based on user input.

Comment: @JRegan - Remove the `Call` statement - it's obsolete. Otherwise, wrap the parameter in parentheses: `Call MAIN(True)`.

Comment: Removed the     Call statement and wrapped the TRUE which allowed me to put it in but I still get 1 for both answers. Is there anything else that may trip this up? I'm using the same as what you have above at the moment. Also will having TRUE next to only one sub limit me to 2 options under false/true?

Comment: @JRegan - You can pass anything you need for a parameter. As far as determining why you're always getting 1, I'd need to see your actual code. The example above should return 1 from B and 2 from A.

Comment: I haven't put this into my code yet, just testing so it's in 3 separate subs (all in the same module) with the only difference being that I have included 'Msgbox Answer' to output the value at the end of the MAIN sub. Everything else is identical. Very strange..

Comment: Ah never mind this was completely my mistake. I had 2 buttons setup to trigger sub a and b and somehow had them pointing to A... This does indeed work perfectly so thanks very much for your help, I've already found many ways to use the optional arguments!